# Pandas: 2 data frames have different shapes but no different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have 2 dataframes: a and b.

When I run `print(a.shape, b.shape)`, I get the following result: `(1, 28849) (44, 29025)` meaning that b has more columns that a. When I run `b.columns.difference(a.columns)` the result is a null index: (`Index([], dtype='object'`). I get the same result when I run `a.columns.difference(b.columns)`. Why do the dataframes have different columns counts in shape but not have any different columns between them?

Comment: Do they share column labels?

Comment: @Will From what I can tell they do share the same column labels. I ran set(a.columns) == set(b.columns) and got True.

Comment: Probably best to share some data examples so we can see

Comment: Ok I think I might have found the source of the discrepancy. After exporting and reimporting both csv's, a different column came up as: `{'Unnamed: 0'}`. Any ideas on what that might mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do the dataframes have different columns counts in shape but not
>   have any different columns between them?

Empty bi-directional [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) is no guarantee that columns in 2 dataframes are the same. Consider the following example:

```
A = pd.DataFrame(columns=[1, 1, 2, 3, 4])
B = pd.DataFrame(columns=[1, 2, 3, 4])

A.columns.difference(B.columns)  # Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
B.columns.difference(A.columns)  # Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
```

`pd.Index.difference` can be compared to `set.difference`, i.e. it does not consider duplicates. If you print the columns explicitly, you should see they are different.

Or, to explicitly calculate the counts of each column name, you can use `numpy.unique`:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.unique(A.columns, return_counts=True))

(array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64), array([2, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!